# Make autoconf "check" target without running it

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, autotools, autoconf, automake

Is there a way to compile the "check" target of an autoconf project without running it?

I have Eclipse Juno with the "C/C++ Unit Test" plugin.  I would like to be able to make the check target, then run it in the context of the plugin so that I can take advantage of its conveniences.

Currently I have set up the project configuration to build "make check" then run the "test" binary that it creates.  This has 2 problems.

1) It is redundant and slows the process (the test runs twice)

2) A test failure causes a build failure.  Eclipse doesn't know the difference.  I have to pay attention to the output, then run in the unit test plugin anyway to get what I want out of it.

If there is no way to just compile the check target, is there some other way of setting up autoconf / automake to allow me to build the test target without creating a special config that builds the test as part of "make all"?  Basically, I want to have all 3 options in a single configuration:

```
make unitTest (for development)
make check    (for automated testing)
make all      (for release)
```

EDIT: Just to clarify a bit, I know I can run "make targetName" from the target directory to compile that target (project/src/test> make myUnitTests).  I'm looking for a generic way to do it from the project's base directory (project> make check_PROGRAMS).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
make check TESTS=
```

will run the `check` target but not invoke any tests.

Comment: This is the correct answer to my base question, and for the generic use case because most people will probably want to compile the main application before the test.  

I really like adl's answer and it applies to my specific use case, but it only works if the "check" test is disconnected from the main app.  In my case, I have gtests that exercise the app source files without needing the app compiled.

Comment: Nice! This is the best `automake` hack I have found to date to solve the common compilation issue. It works with "foreign" layouts too where the tests are stored in subdirs.

Answer (score 5):

How about adding a new rule you your root `Makefile.am`?

```
.PHONY: unitTest
unitTest:
        cd src/test && $(MAKE) $(AM_MAKEFLAGS) myUnitTests
```

and if `make myUnitTests` should build all `$(check_PROGRAMS)` from `src/test/Makefile.am`, just add such a rule in `src/test/Makefile.am`:

```
.PHONY: myUnitTests
myUnitTests: $(check_PROGRAMS)
```

Comment: +1 ... I accepted @WilliamPursell's answer because it answers my top question, but this is the answer for my specific situation where I don't want to compile the main app, just the test app alone.  Wish I could accept both. :-)